# How to invoke sendKeys() method with uppercase letters through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I need some advice to solve the following issue:
I tried to write a text with uppercase letters into search bar, and I received this error message:
`"Must provide a location for a move action."`

```
Actions a=new Actions(driver); 
a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox"))).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("hello").build().perform();
```

Comment: Maybe if you break up the long chain of commands into individual commands, you would be able to see exactly where your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `click()` method before `keyDown()` method:

```
a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox")))
    .click()
    .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys("hello")
    .build()
    .perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a character sequence with *uppercase letters* into search bar you can use the `toUpperCase()` function and you can use the following solution:

```
String myText =  "hello";
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox"))).click().sendKeys(myText.toUpperCase()).build().perform();
```

Comment: To make this to work, `click()` method is needed before `sendKeys()`

Comment: @BOB Updated answer to cater to your requirement. Let me know the status.